# Absolutely incorrect answer accepted

Tags: discussion

[Difference between Maida and All purpose flour](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/14789/difference-between-maida-and-all-purpose-flour) This one particularly bugs me because the question has almost 60,000 views. I find it vaguely embarrassing. The OP has not been back since two days after posting the question and the person who posted the answer was last seen September 2012. Can we unaccept that answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, the OP has the final say, as unfortunate as it is in this case. Probably the best thing for future visitors is to simply edit it into a correct answer. I'll change it to community wiki, to make it clear that it's not owned by the original author anymore, and avoid unfairly giving out rep. Feel free to edit away, if you know the real answer.

Comment: OK, I'm on it. When I'm done I will flag the obsolete comments. Of course the first thing I did was Google "difference between maida and all purpose." Naturally that answer is the first hit.

Comment: You really, **really** shouldn't do that. The community [has made it abundantly clear](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78438/141911) that this is part of how the system works. There's even a [badge](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/badges/39/populist) for scoring better than the accepted answer, which you're potentially depriving someone of if you mess with it. The general consensus is, only "fix" accepted answers if there's a minor mistake. The same guidelines that [apply to editing in general](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) apply to accepted answers!

Comment: @Aaronut Well, okay, feel free to revert it all then. I'm not entirely sure that people getting badges is more important than avoiding having something wrong on top of a page a ton of people are arriving at via Google, or preserving the will of an OP who didn't know it was wrong and is never coming back, but... if that's the community consensus, okay.

Comment: @Aaronut  I saved the text of my answer, so if you guys decide to revert the question, just do it quickly but let me know first. I'll reverse my upvote on the accepted answer and add the current text as **my** answer. Since the current upvotes (including mine) only stand at 3, my downvote on the original answer plus any upvotes **my** answer gets, it shouldn't take long for my correct answer to "outvote" the original accepted answer. I don't know if it's possible to restore SAJ's comment and upvotes to that comment, but that should be done as well if the original accepted answer is restored.

Comment: @Jefromi See above and Holy *Crap* that sounds complicated.

Comment: Now that I think of it I guess it doesn't matter if you let me know first, just let me know quickly. You know if you @ - me, it won't take me long to get the message.

Answer (score 0):

I'll upvote a better answer and downvote the accepted answer. Others will too. It bugs me that the OP accepted an incorrect answer but that's how the system works.

I don't think a minor edit will save the wrong answer.

I suggest you answer it yourself and let the votes work their magic. Even if you don't have the big green check, the point difference will be there and you can always mention the accepted answer in the text of your answer, "Contrary to what is stated in the accepted answer..."

Comment: So far my "edit" (which is actually a completely different answer) is standing. If it gets reverted back to the incorrect answer, I'll post what is now the "accepted" as my answer.